# STL code typedef typename value_type, size_type etc. how do these work?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, typedef

Within certain STL classes you can find code like this (taken from the vector header):

```
        // TEMPLATE CLASS _Vector_val
template<class _Val_types>
    class _Vector_val
        : public _Container_base
    {   // base class for vector to hold data
public:
    typedef _Vector_val<_Val_types> _Myt;
    typedef typename _Val_types::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename _Val_types::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename _Val_types::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename _Val_types::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename _Val_types::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename _Val_types::reference reference;
    typedef typename _Val_types::const_reference const_reference;

    typedef _Vector_iterator<_Myt> iterator;
    typedef _Vector_const_iterator<_Myt> const_iterator;

    _Vector_val()
        {   // initialize values
        _Myfirst = pointer();
        _Mylast = pointer();
        _Myend = pointer();
        }

    pointer _Myfirst;   // pointer to beginning of array
    pointer _Mylast;    // pointer to current end of sequence
    pointer _Myend; // pointer to end of array
    };
```

What I don't understand (and don't know how to effectively google search) is how these lines of code work and what they are doing:

```
typedef typename _Val_types::value_type value_type;
```

For instance, why is value_type apparently within the namespace of _Val_types?

In addition, why there is what appears to be a function call here?:
`_Myfirst = pointer();`

Hopefully someone can explain how this works or direct me to some relevant sites that explain it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The function calls are in the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_Val_types` is not a namespace name, it is whatever type `class _Vector_val` is instantiated with. You are not allowed to use namespace names as template arguments.

```
typedef typename _Val_types::value_type value_type;
```

On the above line you're creating a type named `value_type` which is an alias for a nested type, also named `value_type` that is defined within the `_Val_types` type. The reason for the `typename` keyword is that it is required when you're referring to a dependent type (`value_type` depends on the type of `_Val_types`), refer to [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/241631) for additional details.

```
_Myfirst = pointer();
```

The above line is default constructing a `pointer` and assigning that value to `_Myfirst`. If `pointer` is a trivial type, let's say `_Val_types` is `int` and `_Val_type::pointer` is defined as `int *`, then the above expression will value-initialize an `int *`, which means it zero initializes it, and zero can convert to `nullptr`. Long story short, it's setting the `_Myfirst` data member to `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Praetorian, the notion of dependent types and the information you linked about them in the associated question/answer was exactly what I was looking for.